# NLST result without the directory from vsftpd

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

Is there a config in VSFTPD where `NLST <dir>` send back only the `filename` and not `<dir>/<filename>` ?

```
ftp> nlist OUT
227 Entering Passive Mode (149,202,207,54,212,185).
150 Here comes the directory listing.
OUT/M41_RIC_20210210093105645.CSV
OUT/M41_RIC_20210211095039186.CSV
OUT/M51_RIC_T19048_115_26102020_20201028114231.csv
226 Directory send OK.
```

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vsftpd, the names in `NLST` output are always relative to the current working directory.

I believe the point of this is that the FTP client can use `NLST path` output when implementing `mget path`-like client command. It can simply do `RETR filepath` for each line returned by `NLST`, without trying to understand the semantics of the remote paths.

*You have opposed in a comment that Microsoft IIS does not return the path in `NLST <dir>` result. Indeed it does not. And Microsoft's own `ftp.exe` fails to download files from an IIS subfolder when you do `mget <dir>` because of that. Interestingly `NLST <dir>/<subdir>` in IIS returns the paths. So `mget <dir>/<subdir>` against IIS works.*

---

To get a list without any paths, change the working directory and do `NLST` without any arguments:

```
CWD OUT
NLST
```